# Amazon Lightsail email not working without any error

Tags: amazon-web-services, codeigniter, email, amazon-ec2, amazon-lightsail

Created instance on Amazon Lightsail and install vestacp after that hosted codeigniter application, keep nameservers of AWS, and for MX record using third party.

But unfortunately email not received on email id. When print mail function always display true.

Same thing working fine on EC2 instance.

Please suggest what's wrong I am doing in Lightsail.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your Instance or Amazon FW is catching your instance as a spam carder instance.
Contact Amazon Support center.